# プログラミング初心者がサーバーを作るにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: xss

ブラウザのクロスドメインを回避するために、　[YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) や [AAO](http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/) や [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) でプロキシサーバーを作って回避していたのです。 しかし、以上のサーバーは海外のIPなので[一部のサイト](http://www.anitube.se/)にアクセスできません。

そこで、国内の IP で自分でサーバーを作りたいのですが、やり方がいまいちよくわかりません。僕が今使っているプロバイダは[ここ](http://www.tamashima.tv/add/internet/charge.html)なのですがDHCPらしく動的にIPが変わるのではないかと思いまず何からしたらいいのかよくわかりません。まだ未成年でクレジットカードが持てず Azure や AWS や Heroku などは使えません。

使える言語は C, C++, C#, Java, Python, Perl, Ruby, PHP, JS, Scala, Go, UWSC ぐらいしか使えません。 出来れば、 RaspberryPi で Python を使って低消費電力で運用できたらなぁと思っております。

やりたい事は、クロスドメインで `XMLHttpRequest` などで [Anitube](http://www.anitube.se/) のレスポンスを取得したいのですが、まず何をしたらいいのかご教授いただけると幸いです。

＜追記1＞
[DEMO](http://anime-japan.appspot.com/?url=http://www.anitube.se/)
コードとしては以下のような感じにしたいのですが

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #パラメータのurlを取得
        url = self.request.get('url')
        #getでリソースの取得
        res = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        #text/htmlを出力
        self.response.write(res.content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: [Hiroshi Yamamoto](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/4978/hiroshi-yamamoto)さん訂正していただきありがとうございます。

Comment: 「サーバ」が示すものが幅広いため、質問に少し曖昧なところが残ってしまっていると思います。なんだか個人的に使う動画取得ツールか、分析サイトを作ろうとされてるのですかね？適切なタイトルを思いつかなかったので、 Japanish さんで変更してくださると助かります。

Comment: [Hiroshi Yamamoto](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/4978/hiroshi-yamamoto)さんご指摘ありがとうございます。コードとしては以上のような感じにしたいです。(Pythonです。)

Comment: [mattn](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/440/mattn)さん訂正していただきありがと‌​うございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サーバというよりも、サービスを目的とされているようですね。
Webアプリケーションの形でツールを作ることが目的なら、Herokuなどの無料で使えるPaaSサービスを利用するのが近道だと思います。
以下は回り道をしたい場合のお話です。
自宅でサーバを構築するのに固定IPアドレスを購入する必要はありません。[ダイナミックDNS](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0#.E5.80.8B.E4.BA.BA.E5.90.91.E3.81.91.E5.B8.B8.E6.99.82.E6.8E.A5.E7.B6.9A.E5.9B.9E.E7.B7.9A.E3.81.AB.E3.81.8A.E3.81.91.E3.82.8B.E3.83.80.E3.82.A4.E3.83.8A.E3.83.9F.E3.83.83.E3.82.AFDNS)という、サーバのIPが変わる度に追跡してドメイン登録を更新できるサービスがあります。これを利用すれば普通のURLでサーバを公開できます。日本でも無料でサービスを行っているところがいくつかあります。
LAN外にサーバを公開する場合は、ルータの設定を調整して80番ポートを開放する必要があります。ポートの遮断を解除できないプロバイダもあるようですが、Japanishさんのお使いの[プロバイダのサービス表](http://www.tamashima.tv/add/internet/charge.html)を見るに解除できる望みはあると思います。

Comment: [snipsnipsnip](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/5910/snipsnipsnip)さん回答してくださりありがとうございます。ダイナミックDNSを初めて知りました。もっとダイナミックDNSについて調べてみようと思います。プロバイダの方にも問い合わせてみたいと思います。回答してくださりありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

Heroku はクレジットカードを明示しなくても無料範囲内でアプリケーションを作れます。
以下、私が運用している物です。

- http://mruby.herokuapp.com/
  [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby) という ruby の組み込み系実装を使ってWebサーバをheroku上で稼働させています。
  ソースは https://github.com/mattn/mruby.herokuapp.com にあります。
- http://osusume.herokuapp.com/
  ruby の sinatra を使って、heroku の postgresql と連携しながらチャットサービス[lingr](http://lingr.com)内で動作するbotを稼働させています。
  ソースは https://github.com/akechi/osusume-lingrbot にあります。
- http://vim-jp.herokuapp.com/
  golang と heroku の postgresql を使って http://vim-jp.org/ 内の動的コンテンツや上記 lingr の vim 部屋にいる bot を稼働させています。
  ソースは https://github.com/mattn/vim-jp.herokuapp.com にあります。
- http://golang.herokuapp.com/
  同じく lingr の golang 部屋にいる bot を稼働させています。
  https://github.com/mattn/golang_herokubot

他にも、[appfog](https://www.appfog.com/) も無料(クレカ提示なし)で使えます。
以上、ご参考までに。

**追記**

heroku は herokupack という物を使う事で他にも色んな言語でアプリケーションを作る事が出来ます。
以下は上記 appfog の java で clojure アプリケーションを書いた時の記事です。

http://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/lang/clojure/20130215211135.htm

個人的な意見ですが、ruby を覚えて sinatra でアプリケーションを書くのが簡単だと思います。
※やりたい内容によっては sinatra では出来ない場合もあります。

Comment: [mattn](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/440/mattn)さん回答してくださりありがとうございます。Herokuに興味がでてきました。Herokuやsinatraを勉強していこうと思います。

Comment: 他にも Google Appengine も無料で使えます。ただし Google Appengine は Google が提供するライブラリを使う必要がある為、管理面や稼働率の高さの反面で一長一短です。

Comment: AppEngineやHeroku以外に国内のPaaSはありませんか？
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

国内で、ということなので[GehirnRS2 | ゲヒルンサービスサイト](http://www.gehirn.jp/rs2.html)というレンタルサーバーはどうでしょうか。無料ではありませんが、月額300円＋税と安価にもかかわらずターミナル等からのリモートログインが可能です。

管理者権限はもらえませんが、`rs2`コマンドという独自コマンドを使うことで、ある程度のフレームワークは簡単に導入することができます。
最初から`screen`が導入されていたり、各種設定ファイル(いわゆる`dotfiles`）がコメント付きでチューニングされていたりとちょっと癖があるかもしれません（便利かとは思います）

支払いはクレジットカードを持っていなくても可能です。

---

自宅鯖を検討されるのでしたら、@snipsnipsnip さんのいうようにDDNSを検討されると良いでしょう。尚、`Raspberry pi`はちょっとしたWebサーバには良いかもしれませんが、永続的に使おうとするとSDカードまわりのトラブル(データが飛ぶなど)に巻き込まれることがありますので、ご注意ください。

Comment: [3100](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3313/3100)さん回答してくださりありが‌​とうございます。GehirnRS2のお試し版を試してみようと思いました。個人的には、インフラ関係の勉強もしてみたいのでこれを機会にDDNSについてやってみようと思います。回答‌​してくださりありがとうございました。